# every time i open 2 or more windows - it crashes - restart itself

Tags: 12.04

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and problem is that every time i open 2 or more windows - it crashes - restart itself. Sometimes it crash when I just type something - what is the problem? What other Ubuntu program would you recommend instead 12.04?

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! ubuntu is an OS not a program. Your question is vague, we need more information like: What is your PC/laptop vendor? Model? Graphics Card and Vendor? Have you installed anything non-default yet? What have you done so far to eliminate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a hardware fault, there are a few things to think about:

- If you just leave it running with no windows open does it work reliably?
- Does it fail immediately when you open the second window/program?
- Have you tried different combinations of software to check that it is not a single faulty program?

The easiest thing to check is a memory fault, which could cause these symptoms.  Reboot and at the grub prompt select the 'memtest' option, leave it to run for a couple of hours at least and see if it reports any problems.

Even if it doesn't, it might be worth carefully removing and reseating your memory cards.

If that is all clear, tell us more about the machine, how old it is, has it been used successfully with other operating systems etc, it doesn't sound like an Ubuntu 12.04 specific problem at this stage.